# "An item with the same key has already been added." while adding "/&output=embed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe, oauth, evernote

Implementing a MVC application in C# with Evernote API. I am using the `AsyncOAuth.Evernote.Simple` nuget package. `Receiving and error of Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'`, when trying to navigate to URL that fires off the OAuth process.

There is an iframe that is surrounding my code (which can not be altered). After implementing the code an error is generated: `"An item with the same key has already been added".` This error occurs when `requestToken` is hit for the first time.

Below is my `EvernoteProviderController.cs`

```
public class EvernoteProviderController : Controller
{



    // Initialize Oauth call, pulling values from web.config
   EvernoteAuthorizer EvernoteAuthorizer = new EvernoteAuthorizer(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Evernote.Url"] + "&output=embed", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Evernote.Key"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Evernote.Secret"]);



    // This method makes the original call to Evernote to get a token so that the user can validate that they want to access this site.
    public ActionResult Authorize(bool reauth = false)
    {
        // Allow for reauth
        if (reauth)
            SessionHelper.Clear();

        // First of all, check to see if the user is already registered, in which case tell them that
        if (SessionHelper.EvernoteCredentials != null)
            return Redirect(Url.Action("AlreadyAuthorized"));

        // Evernote will redirect the user to this URL once they have authorized your application
        var callBackUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Url.Action("ObtainTokenCredentials");

        // Generate a request token - this needs to be persisted till the callback
        var requestToken = EvernoteAuthorizer.GetRequestToken(callBackUrl);

        // Persist the token
        SessionHelper.RequestToken = requestToken;

        // Redirect the user to Evernote so they can authorize the app
        var callForwardUrl = EvernoteAuthorizer.BuildAuthorizeUrl(requestToken);
        return Redirect(callForwardUrl);
    }

    // This action is the callback that Evernote will redirect to after the call to Authorize above
    public ActionResult ObtainTokenCredentials(string oauth_verifier)
    {
        // Use the verifier to get all the user details we need and store them in EvernoteCredentials
        var credentials = EvernoteAuthorizer.ParseAccessToken(oauth_verifier, SessionHelper.RequestToken);
        if (credentials != null)
        {
            SessionHelper.EvernoteCredentials = credentials;
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Authorized"));
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Unauthorized"));
        }
    }

    // Show the user if they are authorized
    public ActionResult Authorized()
    {
        return View(SessionHelper.EvernoteCredentials);
    }

    public ActionResult Unauthorized()
    {
        return View();
    }


    //Redirects user if already authorized, then dump out the EvernoteCredentials object
    public ActionResult AlreadyAuthorized()
    {
        return View(SessionHelper.EvernoteCredentials);
    }

    public ActionResult Settings()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Has anyone had this issue with iframes before or knows in what direction I should go? I am trying to embed my URL endpoint so I can get around the iframe error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the error.

*A bit of back story:*

The purpose of this application was to provide the OAuth page where a user can sign up which will generate a `AuthToken` and `NotebookURL`, (both are needed with Evernote API to pull read/write `Notes` - which is Evernote's object).

The previous behavior (before I changed it), was when a user clicked on the link - they will be redirected (in the same window) to the Evernote OAuth page.

This caused issues for me, because I had another wrapper around my code (`iframe`). So in non-technical terms, I had a `iframe` within an `iframe` within an `iframe`.

*Workaround*

Created a JavaScript code which would add an `click` event listener, which would then create a popup using `window.open`.

```
$("#btnStart").click(function () {

    myWindow = window.open(baseUrl + "/EvernoteProvider/Authorize", '_blank', 'width=500,height=500, scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
    myWindow.focus();

});
```